# Are \A \z in String#matches redundant?

Tags: java, regex

In java `String` class the `matches` tests if a string matches a regex pattern. So obviously it is the entire string against the regex pattern, does that mean `\A, \z, ^, $` are redundant here?

If not, please provide examples to show why they are not redundant in this case.

Comment: Yet I remember there is one caveat, I will have to dig much deeper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're redundant unless you activate [multiline mode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#MULTILINE), in which case `^` and `$` would match the beginning and end of individual *lines* instead of the whole input.

You can activate multiline mode while using [`String#matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) by using the embedded flag expression `(?m)` inside the regex (usually at the beginning).

Comment: Good answer, but I can't get a multiline string to match unless I use DOT ALL mode (which is `(?s)` by the way, not `(?m)`).

Comment: `String#matches` only matches the whole string, the multiline mode is not possible there.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sort of.  If you have a string with newlines, and you want `String#matches` to work, then you need `(?s)` in order to get a match.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen You are confusing things. 4castle mentions the `Pattern.MULTILINE` option in the context of `^` and `$` anchors.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew [Here's an example](https://ideone.com/YWs6Qj) of using multiline mode with String.matches.